# When setting up DNS forwarders is it correct or incorrect to use the gateway IP?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dns-hosting

Server 2012 R2

I'm trying finalize my DNS setup after just promoting my first domain controller.  As I ran through the Configure a DNS Wizard, it asked for an IP address to forward DNS queries.  My immediate response was to simply input the gateway address, since the gateway will forward requests up the line.

Is this right, wrong, OK but a less than optimum solution?  I notice it can't resolve the FQDN, but the gateway is just a router so I'm presuming that's not a problem.

I do have some DNS server IP's supplied by my ISP.  Should I be using those instead, in addition to, or pick one or the other - ISP addresses or the gateway IP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not right or wrong. It's entirely up to you. You can use your router as a forwarder, you can use your ISP, you can use Google DNS, OpenDNS or any other public DNS servers **OR** you can choose to not use any forwarders and use the root hints (my preference).

Comment: +1 on using root hints only and not forwarders.